# What does object identity mean in java?

Tags: java, oop, object

I was reading about "Data abstraction" in java language programming that I faced with this phrase:

> Objects in java are characterized by three essential properties: ***state***, ***identity***, and ***behavior***. The state of an object is a value from its
>   data type. **The identity of an object distinguishes one object from
>   another**. It is useful to think of an object’s identity as **the place
>   where its value is stored in memory**.

Can everyone explain more specifically what is the identity ?

Comment: Think of *identity* as anything that *uniquely* identifies an Object. It could be an address in memory or just a random number.

Comment: Isn't this explained in the last sentence?

Comment: Think of two wheels of a car. Both can turn (behavior), both are resting (state) but one is the left front wheel, and one is the right front wheel (identity)

Comment: Don't overthink it, it basically just means that every object you create with new is going to be different than any other object. They can have the same data they can be equal using equals, behave the same way but they are still going to be different(hence every object has identity). You can see this difference using the == operator.

Comment: Another question I need to upvote to offset the downvotes. Can the downvoters please explain why this is a bad question? OP didn't just copy some code, failed to compile it and came here without reading any documentation. He was reading the documentation! And couldn't understand it. This looks like [something people struggle with](https://coderanch.com/t/514972/java/Explation-Object-Identity) and need help from others. Why is he not welcomed on StackOverflow?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Suppose you have this simple class:

```
class Example {
    private int value;

    Example(int v) {
        this.value = v;
    }

    public void showValue() {
        System.out.println(this.value);
    }
}
```

And we have this code (for instance, in a method somewhere else):

```
Example e1 = new Example(42);
Example e2 = new Example(42);
```

Then:

- `e1` and `e2` have *state* (their `value` member). In this case, it happens both have the same state (42).
- `e1` and `e2` have *behavior*: A method, `showValue`, that will dump out their value to the console. (Note that they don't necessarily have to have the *same* behavior: We could create a subclass of `Example` that did something different with `showValue` [perhaps showed it in a pop-up dialog box], and make `e2` an instance of that subclass instead.)
- `e1` and `e2` have *identity*: The expression `e1 == e2` is `false`; they are not the same object. They each have a unique identity. They may be *equivalent* objects (we could implement `equals` and `hashCode` such that they were deemed equivalent), but they will never have the same identity.

No object ever has the same identity as another object; an object's identity is guaranteed unique within the memory of the running process.

(They also have other characteristics, such as their class type, but those are the main three.)

Comment: Is object's **default* identity same as its reference? or pointer?

Comment: What do you mean by "default identity"? I'm not familiar with that term, and it doesn't seem to appear anywhere in the JLS: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22default+identity%22+site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2Fspecs%2Fjls%2Fse19%2Fhtml

Comment: By "default identity" I mean the identity inferred by the default implementation of `equals()` as described in Baeldung's tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/java-equals-hashcode-contracts

Comment: @WebViewer - If you're talking about `Object` version of `equals`, it uses `==`, which is [defined here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.3). Basically, it uses object identity. Yes, you could *loosely* call that reference/pointer equality, although really it just means that the operands have to refer to the same object. (It's entirely possible for a JVM to implement its reference mechanism such that two slightly different reference values mean the same thing and thus refer to the same object -- such a JVM would have to ensure == was true in that case).

Answer (score 1):

I can think in these two examples from the C++ world.

Example 1: objects a and b are not identical, because they don't share the same memory.

```
Someclass a;
Someclass b;
```

Example 2: objects a and b are identical because they point to the same object.

```
Someclass c;
Someclass* a = &c;
Someclass* b = &c;
```